# SocketIO Disconnect Leaving Socket Listening

Tags: node.js, sockets, coffeescript, socket.io

I am attempting to use SocketIO combined with Redis Pub/Sub to monitor events in my application. So far, I have something like the following for the server

```
io.on 'connection', (socket) ->
  log.info "Connection established. [Socket: #{socket.id}]"

  socket.on 'join_room', (roomName) ->
    log.info "Join room '#{roomName}'. [Socket: #{socket.id}]"
    socket.join roomName

  redis.on 'message', (redisChannel, message) ->
    message = JSON.parse message
    log.info "Room: #{message.room} - Event: #{message.event} - Message: #{message.message}"
    io.sockets.in(message.room).emit(message.event, message.message)

  socket.on 'disconnect', ->
    log.info "Connection destroyed. [Socket #{socket.id}]"
```

Then, on the client, I have

```
  socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3333/')   
  socket.emit('join_room', 'login_events')
  socket.emit('join_room', 'cj_alerts')

  socket.on 'failed_login', (msg) ->
    console.log msg

  socket.on 'successful_login', (msg) ->
    console.log msg
```

When the server is running, I can use `$redis.publish 'redisChannel', {:room => 'room', :event => 'failed_login', :message => 'message'}.to_json` to get the `redis.on 'message'` bit to fire correctly. In fact, everything works very well.

The problem comes when I refresh the page that the client code is located on without restarting the server. My "Connection destroyed" log comes up correctly, but it seems that the connection never truly dies. With each refresh, another listener is added. The screenshot below should help clear up what I mean.

Each "Connection destroyed"/"Connection established" signals a refresh.

[image]

I also assumed that the code on the client side would be on a per browser window basis. However, even when I open a new browser, I'm getting output that says *all* of the events are being applied to each window.

Any tips on why it's doing what it is and the correct way to it would be appreciated.

Comment: Your client code is "per browser window", not "per client" so there will be a unique connection for each browser window.  You would have to use some sort of persistent user identifier to make anything per client and then code to enforce a one connection per client policy.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll reword it. That is what I meant. As in, with Chrome, Chrome in incognito, and Firefox open, all three get the `console.log` from the client code once for each of the listeners that is open in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the location of my `redis.on 'message'` listener. I was listenting for that on each and every socket that I created. In reality, I only needed to listen for it in a global sense and *then* message any rooms. This looks like this:

```
io.on 'connection', (socket) ->
  log.info "Connection established. [Socket: #{socket.id}]"

  socket.on 'join_room', (roomName) ->
    log.info "Join room '#{roomName}'. [Socket: #{socket.id}]"
    socket.join roomName

  socket.on 'disconnect', ->
    log.info "Connection destroyed. [Socket #{socket.id}]"

redis.on 'message', (redisChannel, message) ->
  message = JSON.parse message
  log.info "Room: #{message.room} - Event: #{message.event} - Message: #{message.message}"
  io.sockets.in(message.room).emit(message.event, message.message)
```